# How to diagnose Request_Cacnelled in HTTPERR log

Tags: iis, httpserver, httpservice, http.sys

I have an ASP.NET web API app hosted on IIS 10, there are tons of Request_Cacnelled log appear in HTTPERR log.

I suspect that may be due to some hang-on requests but after checking `HTTP Service Request Queues\Current Queue Size`, `HTTP Service Request Queues\Arrival Rate`, `ASP.NET Applications\Requests / Sec`, `ASP.NET Applications\Request Execution Time` per counters, they all not showed an increase.

What's the possible reason may cause `Request_Cacnelled` and how should I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

If the timeout in your Httpclient is greater than the timeout in the service, the error Request_Cancelled will appear.

You can try to set the timeout in your Httpclient smaller.

In addition, you can also get more detailed information through this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109148/13336642.