# network reset with long text coming from php

Tags: php, iis, server

I have two boxes:

`A: IIS 8.5.9600 on Windows Server 2012 R2`

`B: IIS 8.0.9200 on Windows Server 2012`

`php version is the same: 7.4.13`

when a simple php script in box `A` outputs more than 4MB I get in the browser: `NS_ERROR_NET_RESET`

On the other hand, this does not happen on Box `B`, it seems immune. If this is caused by IIS, it seems that the newer version (8.5) is at fault while the older (8.0) works fine.

I have narrowed down it happening when just a simple query from the db brings a 7MB text, but the problem occurs as soon as I pass 4MB.

but the query is not necessary, even this simple script causes the problem:

```
$s = str_repeat("a", 4200000);
//just a string with length slightly more than 4MB
echo $s;
```

So it happens when the output from php is larger than 4MB

- (IIS) `maxAllowedContentLength` is at 30MB so not an issue (checked it in iis manager)
- (PHP) `memory_limit` = 256MB so not an issue (checked it in php.ini)

edit: the error i get in IIS error logs is `Request_Cancelled`

How can I further find out the root of the problem and solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can try to capture and analyze http.sys etl log to find the root cause for Request cancelled, about how to capture http.sys etl log you can refer to this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109148/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109148/13336642).

Comment: I will try that, thank you